# How can I convert these nested loops into an R loop function like sapply or tapply or

Tags: r

I have this code which I run over a data frame t.

```
for (i in years){
    for (j in type){
            x <- rbind(x, cbind(i, j, 
                       sum(t[(t$year == i) & (t$type == j),]$Emissions, 
                           na.rm = TRUE)))
}
}
```

Basically, I have two vectors `years` and `type`. I'm finding the sum of each category and merging that into a data frame. The above code works, but I cannot figure out how to use one of the loop functions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are ways to do this using the apply functions.  I'm going to suggest a high performance approach using dplyr, though.

```
library(dplyr)
x <- t %>% 
     group_by(year,type) %>% 
     summarize(SumEmmissions=sum(Emissions,na.rm=TRUE))
```

I think you will find that it is much faster than either a loop or apply approach.

=================== Proof, as requested ===============

`library(dplyr)
N <- 1000000
Nyear <- 50
Ntype <- 40
myt <- data.frame(year=sample.int(50,N,replace=TRUE),
                type=sample.int(4,N,replace=TRUE),
                Emissions=rnorm(N)
               )
years <- 1:Nyear
type <- 1:Ntype
v1 <- function(){
  x <- myt %>%
       group_by(year,type) %>%
       summarize(SumEmmissions=sum(Emissions,na.rm=TRUE))
}
v2 <- function(){
  x <- data.frame()
  for (i in years){
    for (j in type){
      x <- rbind(x, cbind(i, j,
                          sum(myt[(myt$year == i) & (myt$type == j),]$Emissions, na.rm = TRUE)))
    }
  }
}
v3 <- function(){
  t0 <- myt[myt$year %in% years & myt$type %in% type, ]
  x <- aggregate(Emissions ~ year + type, t0, sum, na.rm = TRUE)
}
system.time(v1())
   user  system elapsed 
  0.051   0.000   0.051 
system.time(v2())
   user  system elapsed 
176.482   0.402 177.231 
system.time(v3())
   user  system elapsed 
  7.758   0.011   7.783`

As the sizes and number of groups increases, so does the performance spread.

Comment: This solution ignores the input `years` and `type` vectors and so only works if those vectors contain all the years and types.

Comment: That's true.  My reading was that `years` and `type` were created only to facilitate summarization.  If the OP wants to subset as well through choice of those vectors, he will need to include a `filter(year %in% years, type %in% type)` verb as well (or use your subset suggestion).  The `type` vector should be named something reasonable like `types`...not sure whether my filter command works with the ambiguity introduced by this variable name choice.

Answer (score 1):

Pick out all rows for which `year` is in `years` and `type` is in `type` giving `t0`.  Then aggregate `Emissions` based on `years` and `type`.

```
t0 <- t[t$year %in% years & t$type %in% type, ]
aggregate(Emissions ~ year + type, t0, sum, na.rm = TRUE)
```

If the `years` and `type` vectors contain all years and types then the first line could be omitted and `t0` in the second line replaced with `t`.

Next time please make your example reproducible.

**Update** Some corrections.